# In a Mercurial repository, how to find lastly committed 10 files contained in a subdirectory?

Tags: search, mercurial, find, commit

In a Mercurial repository, how to find lastly committed 10 files contained in a subdirectory? I want to do so because I'm a little worried that some files are mistakenly committed.

Answer (score 1):

Using [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) is probably the best approach.

A close approximation may be `hg log -r "last(file('subdirectory/*'), 10)"`.

This command returns the last 10 commits that touched any file in subdirectory.  From there, you could review each commit for the files affected.

If `--template "{files}\n"` is added to the command, it will list the files touched in each of the commits.  However, the list would include files outside subdirectory as well.  See [hg help templates](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/templating) for details.